# How to read the WFG of a deadlock from a oracle 11g Rac trace file?

Tags: oracle11g, database-deadlocks

> *** 2013-10-26 21:33:16.156
>
> Submitting asynchronized dump request [28]. summary=[ges process stack dump (kjdglblkrdm1)].
>
> Global blockers dump end:-----------------------------------
>
> Global Wait-For-Graph(WFG) at ddTS[0.2c75] :
>
> BLOCKED 0xb5fa75090 5 wq 2 cvtops x1001 TX 0x370009.0x5ac02(ext 0x4,0x0)[46D000-0002-0000542E] inst 2
>
> BLOCKER 0xb5fa74950 5 wq 1 cvtops x28 TX 0x370009.0x5ac02(ext 0x4,0x0)[335000-0002-000178BA] inst 2
>
> BLOCKED 0xb5fa75260 5 wq 2 cvtops x1001 TX 0x34001e.0x4ea93(ext 0x4,0x0)[335000-0002-000178BA] inst 2
>
> BLOCKER 0xb5fa74028 5 wq 1 cvtops x28 TX 0x34001e.0x4ea93(ext 0x4,0x0)[46D000-0002-0000542E] inst 2
>
> - Cancel deadlock victim lockp 0xb5fa75090
>
> kjddt2vb: valblk  [0.2c76] > local ts [0.2c75]

First, I know what is a deadlock.

My question is:

In a LINE of this WFG, what's the meaning of every part?

Especially, Which part is XID?